# Log when my ASP.NET Core app launches successfully or when it doesn't

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core-2.0, serilog

So I've recently started with creating and programming an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application. I've been getting the logging to work using Serilog and I can write to a .txt log file on my local computer. The path to this file is written in my appsettings.json file which is read from my Startup.ConfigureServices method just fine.

However I want to log from my Program class for when my ASP.NET Core app launches succesfully or when it doesn't. The problem is: How can i read my appsettings.json file to get the log file path from my Program class so that I can log to that file?

I've tried:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
var configuration = builder.Build();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel
    .Information().
    WriteTo.RollingFile(configuration.GetValue<string>("LogFilePath") + "-{Date}.txt", LogEventLevel.Information)
    //.WriteTo.Log4Net()
    .CreateLogger();
```

From my Program.cs but it can't read my appsettings.json.
I've double checked that the GetValue uses the correct key.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be missing `SetBasePath` on the `ConfigurationBuilder` (see Simple Configuration section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration)). See example below which also caters for environment specific overrides of appsettings.

```
public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        var configuration = builder.Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile(configuration.GetValue<string>("LogFilePath") + "-{Date}.txt", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting web host");
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Web Host terminated unexpectedly");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging((ctx, builder) =>
        {
            builder.ClearProviders();
            builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
            builder.AddSerilog();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
}
```

Comment: That's a great tip man thanks. Now I can use my configuration in my Main method as well.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using a static Log class with loggerconfiguration like this:

**Inside Startup.ConfigureServices()**

```
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel
            .Information().
            WriteTo.RollingFile(Configuration.GetValue<string>("LogFilePath") + "-{Date}.txt", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .CreateLogger();
        //all the services.add code...
```

**And in my Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);

        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<UpdateServerContext>();
                DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
            }
        }

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting web host");
            host.Run();
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Starting web host failed.");
        }
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

In this way Log only gets used when it's already made from the Startup class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = BuildWebHost(args);
    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

        var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

        //Do some logging
    }

    host.Run();
}
```

Comment: I fixed it by defining Logger.Logger in Startup and logging in Program after WebHost was build. Thanks for you answer

Comment: Great that you solved it! Maybe post the answer so that others can see it?